# spark streaming with mongodb in java

Tags: java, mongodb, apache-spark, spark-streaming

In my application, I want to stream data from MongoDB to Spark Streaming in Java. For this purpose, I used queue stream, because i thought i can keep mongodb data on rdd. but this method doesn't work or I did something wrong.

Do anyone stream from mongodb to spark streaming? Is my way wrong, if yes, what is the correct way?

my code is here

```
package com.mongodb.spark.stream;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.FlatMapFunction;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Durations;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaReceiverInputDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext;
import org.bson.BSONObject;

import com.mongodb.hadoop.MongoInputFormat;

import scala.Tuple2;

public class MongoStream {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    conf.set("mongo.job.input.format", "com.mongodb.hadoop.MongoInputFormat");
    conf.set("mongo.input.uri", "mongodb://192.168.1.149:27017/test.observations");

    SparkConf spc = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("mongo");

    JavaStreamingContext sc = new JavaStreamingContext(spc, Durations.seconds(1));

    final Queue q = new LinkedList<JavaRDD<String>>();

    final JavaPairRDD<Object, BSONObject> rdd = sc.sparkContext().newAPIHadoopRDD(conf, MongoInputFormat.class,
            Object.class, BSONObject.class);

    JavaRDD<String> words = rdd.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<Tuple2<Object, BSONObject>, String>() {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -5974149698144908239L;

        @Override
        public Iterable<String> call(Tuple2<Object, BSONObject> arg0) throws Exception {

            Object o = arg0._2.get("SensorId").toString();
            if (o instanceof String) {
                String str = (String) o;
                str = str.replace("[.,!?|\n]", " ");
                System.out.println(str);

                q.add(str.split(""));
                System.out.println("dsdssd : " + q);
                return Arrays.asList(str.split(" "));

            } else
                return Collections.emptyList();

        }
    });

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    JavaReceiverInputDStream<String> rec = (JavaReceiverInputDStream<String>) sc.queueStream(q);

}

}
```

Comment: Please add your code to illustrate the issue you are confronting. The question is very vague as it stands at the moment.

Comment: @maasg I added my code.

Comment: @vedat  Do you have any significant exception in this situation? Also which block doesn't work in your code, have you debugged it?

Comment: @İlkerKorkut, I debugged it and first JavaRDD block doesn't work. According to my research, queue stream supports Queue<JavaRDD<U>> usage. I created JavaRDD  object for this reason but it doesn'T work.

Comment: may you share your error logs if any?

Comment: @İlkerKorkut don't get any error on logs.  I checked blocks with sysout lines but these blocks doesn't produce any results. when this rdd don't work, rest of the code don't work.

Comment: @vedat `DBObject dbObject=(DBObject) arg0._2.get("SensorId");` In iterable can you check is this DBObject is null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 String brokers = "localhost:2181";
    String group="spark";   

    Map<String, Integer> topicMap = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
            topicMap.put("twitter-topic",1);
    JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext("local[4]", "SparkStream", new  Duration(1200));
      JavaPairReceiverInputDStream<String, String> messages = KafkaUtils.createStream(jssc, brokers, group, topicMap);

    JavaDStream<String> data = messages.map(new Function<Tuple2<String, String>, String>() 
                                                    {
                                                        public String call(Tuple2<String, String> message)
                                                        {
                                                            return message._2();
                                                        }

                                                    });
            data.foreachRDD(new Function<JavaRDD<String>, Void>() {
                Mongo mongo = new Mongo("localhost", 27017);
                DB db = mongo.getDB("mongodb");

                DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("fb");

                public Void call(JavaRDD<String> data) throws Exception {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if(data!=null){
                        List<String>result=data.collect();

                        for (String temp :result) {

                            System.out.println(temp);

                            DBObject dbObject = (DBObject) JSON.parse(temp.toString());

                            collection.insert(dbObject);

                        }
                        System.out.println("Inserted Data Done");

                    }else {
                        System.out.println("Got no data in this window");
                    }

                    return null;
                } 

            });
    jssc.start();
    jssc.awaitTermination();
}
```

Comment: integration of kafka and Spark_streaming with mongodb javacode

Comment: User asked for how to connect Mondo db with spark streaming to read mongo data. But answer is for how to store data to mongo DB from kafka

Answer (score 2):

This method will not work. `QueueDStream` consumes one RDD in the given queue in each interval, so this process is only going to work once.

You can visualize it like this:

`QueueDStream(Queue(RDD-time1, RDD-time2, ...,  RDD-time-n))`

Then on each streaming interval, the RDD instance at the head of the queue will be processed.  If you use a mutable concurrent queue, it's possible for a process to add RDDs on the tail of the queue while Spark Streaming will process the head on each interval.

I'm not aware for Streaming support for Mongo, so probably you will need to rethink this process in other terms. e.g. create your own [Custom Receiver](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-custom-receivers.html)

Answer (score 0):

your use this type means :

```
QueueDStream(Queue(RDD-time1, RDD-time2, ...,  RDD-time-n))
```

this answer:

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("JavaQueueStream");

// Create the context
JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, new Duration(1000));

// Create the queue through which RDDs can be pushed to
// a QueueInputDStream
Queue<JavaRDD<Integer>> rddQueue = new LinkedList<JavaRDD<Integer>>();

// Create and push some RDDs into the queue
List<Integer> list = Lists.newArrayList();
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  list.add(i);
}

for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
  rddQueue.add(ssc.sparkContext().parallelize(list));
}

// Create the QueueInputDStream and use it do some processing
JavaDStream<Integer> inputStream = ssc.queueStream(rddQueue);
JavaPairDStream<Integer, Integer> mappedStream = inputStream.mapToPair(
    new PairFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer>() {
      @Override
      public Tuple2<Integer, Integer> call(Integer i) {
        return new Tuple2<Integer, Integer>(i % 10, 1);
      }
    });
```

Comment: where is any data pulled from mongo in this answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Debezium connector which pushes any changes made to Mongodb database to Kafka and spark can pick up the stream from kafka in real time and do processing